# Generalizing a property of cones to cusps

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

An $\alpha$-cusp with slope $a$  and vertex $z$ is a function  $ C^\alpha: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by
$ C^\alpha := a| x - z |^{\alpha} + b  $ where $  a,b \in \mathbb{R} $.

For a given function $f:D \subset \mathbf{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a real number $\alpha \in [0,1]$  we set for all $A \subset D$
\begin{equation} \label{Holder seminorm}
    [f]_{\alpha,A} : = \inf \left \{ C \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha } \le C \quad \mbox{for all} \quad x \neq y \in A  \right \}.
\end{equation}
I'd like to prove the following result

**Let $ W \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and $ C^{\alpha}_u$ be an $\alpha$-cusp with vertex $ z \notin W $ and slop $ a \in \mathbb{R} $. If  $ u \in C( \overline{W}) $ satisfies $ u = C^{\alpha}_u $ on $ \partial W $ and $ [u]_{\alpha,W} = | a | $, then $ u \equiv C^{\alpha}_u $ in $ W $.**

Suppose that there exists  $ y \in W $ so that $ u(y) \neq C^\alpha_u (y) $, for instance $ u(y) > C^{\alpha}_u (y) $. Let $L$ be the line determined by the vertex $z$ of the cusp $C^{\alpha}_u$ and $y$. Let $y^{*  }$ and $y^{**}$ respectively  the closest and further point in $L \cap \partial W$ in relation to $y    $. If $ a \geq 0 $ we obtain,
$$ u (y) - u(y^{*}) \ > C^{\alpha}_u(y) - C^{\alpha}_u(y^{*})   = a| y - y^{*} |^{\alpha} . $$
The proof for $\alpha =1$ is the case when $C^\alpha_u$ is a cone. You can see detais em (1.4) in here https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-04/S0273-0979-04-01035-3/S0273-0979-04-01035-3.pdf. But we do the proof below.

Notice that we have used the equality in the triangle inequality at the end. For $\alpha \in (0,1)$ So I ask

1. Is there a triangle inequalty for $d(x,y) = |x-y|^\alpha $ that reaches an equality for some $y^*,y^{**}$ similar to the aboves? Maybe instead of a Line passing through $y$ and $z$ we have to find some "cusp" instead a line. Given corrects $y^*,y^{**}$ in this case. If you can find a counterexemplo I appreciate too.

Comment: Some unclear parts: "%When there is no confusion about the $\alpha \in (0,1)$": why could there be confusion? Is this $\alpha$ not the same as the $\alpha$ of $[u]_{\alpha,a}$? Why is there a "%"?

Comment: "For a given function $f$ etc.": there is no mention of $f$ thereafter... - "$[u]_{\alpha,a} := $ etc.": what is $u$? A function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ like $f$?

Comment: I did a mistake here. I will erase this part

Comment: Is there a typo here. I will correct